# ArrayList adapter getting wrong data in listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Anyone know why i am get wrong data in my AdapterClass when am using listview to populate the adapter here is the code I am using

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SchoolClass> {
    ArrayList<SchoolClass> schoolclass;

    private SchoolAdapter schoolAdapter;



    public SchoolAdapter(Activity activity1, ArrayList<SchoolClass> schoolClassList1){
        super(activity1, R.layout.school_adapter, schoolClassList1);
        this.activity = activity1;
        this.schoolClassList = schoolClassList1;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"}) View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.school_adapter, null, false);
        school_name = view.findViewById(R.id.school_name);
        school_size = view.findViewById(R.id.school_size);
        school_btn  = view.findViewById(R.id.school_btn);

        SchoolClass schoolClass = schoolclass.get(position);

        school_name.setText(schoolClass.getSchoolName());
        school_size.setText(schoolClass.getSchool_Size());

                school_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(context, "Grant"+schoolClass.getSchoolName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
}
```

Note: When i use listview.setOnItemClickListerner i get the correct data where it should be but when i use any of the click the item of the first value in the adapter i get the result of like the 5th item and when i click the second item the same thing and when i click the third item i get the result of like the 8th or 9th item in the adapter every other thing seems fine and my code is not showing any error since the result is been display but it isn,t the right result
Note 2: I am using json to retrieve the list but the result is displayed correctly only when i click on the item in the adapter that when i am getting a wrong result in the Toast

Comment: What is this `schoolClass = schoolClass.get(position);`? Can you add more details of your adapter?

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Grant "+ schoolclass.get(position).getName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SchoolClass> {
    ArrayList<SchoolClass> schoolclass;
    Context context

    public SchoolAdapter(Context context ,ArrayList<SchoolClass> schoolClassList){
        super(context, R.layout.school_adapter, schoolClassList);
        this.activity = activity1;
        this.schoolClassList = schoolClassList1;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"}) View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.school_adapter, parent, false);
        school_name = view.findViewById(R.id.school_name);
        school_size = view.findViewById(R.id.school_size);
        school_btn  = view.findViewById(R.id.school_btn);

        schoolClass = schoolclass.get(position);

        school_name.setText(schoolClass.getSchoolName());
        school_size.setText(schoolClass.getSchool_Size());

        school_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Grant"+ schoolclass.get(position).getSchoolName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instance (schoolclass) name are almost same with list name.

Change

```
"schoolClass = schoolClass.get(position);" to
"schoolClass = schoolclass.get(position);"
```

`schoolclass` - is list;
`schoolClass` - is your item, I think you are confusing upper/lower

Comment: i have corrected that and added more details of my code